# Label to the left of checkbox with JFoenix in JavaFX

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8, jfoenix

I am using the [JFoenix](http://jfoenix.com/documentation.html#CheckBox) library for JavaFX, and I wanted to display the check box label to the left of the box.

From (default) :

[image]

To:

[image]

Looking at the available methods, this is the only thing that reads as it would work but it does not do anything (I am guessing it is just for other graphics):

```
checkBox.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
// checkBox.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```

Is there another method or css styling to get the label on the left? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Incase someone still facing the same problem, here is the answer

from java code

```
checkbox.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

from fxml file

```
nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a label and wrap it with the jfxCheckBox in a HBox like below simple way:

```
JFXCheckBox jfxCheckBox = new JFXCheckBox();
HBox hBox = new HBox();
Label label= new Label("CHECK BOX");
hBox.getChildren().addAll(label, jfxCheckBox);
hBox.setSpacing(10);
```

Other way as :

```
Label lblCheckbox = new Label("CHECK BOX");
lblCheckbox.setGraphic(new JFXCheckBox());
lblCheckbox.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Both excellent methods but I would like to know if it possible to move the checkbox's own label.

Comment: How should I change the color of checkbox when it is checked?

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt or override the `layoutChildren()` method of the [`JFXCheckBoxSkin`](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/0d878a33a73d530a6331a272ca90f049d0106dba/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXCheckBoxSkin.java) in order to place the checkbox after its label.

Change the x position of the `layoutLabelInArea()` method such that the label moves/remains to the left. This can be achieved by removing the `boxWidth` from the `xOffset`:

```
layoutLabelInArea(xOffset, yOffset, labelWidth, maxHeight, checkBox.getAlignment());
```

Similarly, move the checkbox to the right by adding the `labelWidth` to the `xOffset`:

```
positionInArea(box, xOffset+labelWidth, yOffset, boxWidth, maxHeight, 0, checkBox.getAlignment()
                .getHpos(), checkBox.getAlignment().getVpos());
```